# an error within a code (only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index)

Tags: python

I got an error within a code which falls into (TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index).
Given the use of enumerate object, I thought the (unit8) has to be converted into (int), but I keep getting the same error. The code is this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

B=8 # blocksize 
img1 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Leith\Desktop\Test Images\Goldhill_Final.bmp')
h,w=np.array(img1.shape[:2])/B * B
h=int(h)
w=int(w)

Trans_Color=cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
Trans_Color=Trans_Color.astype(int)
L,A,B=cv2.split(Trans_Color)

Three_Channels=[Trans_Color[:,:,0],A,B]

QY=np.array([[16,11,10,16,24,40,51,61],
                         [12,12,14,19,26,48,60,55],
                         [14,13,16,24,40,57,69,56],
                         [14,17,22,29,51,87,80,62],
                         [18,22,37,56,68,109,103,77],
                         [24,35,55,64,81,104,113,92],
                         [49,64,78,87,103,121,120,101],
                         [72,92,95,98,112,100,103,99]])

QC=np.array([[17,18,24,47,99,99,99,99],
                         [18,21,26,66,99,99,99,99],
                         [24,26,56,99,99,99,99,99],
                         [47,66,99,99,99,99,99,99],
                         [99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99],
                         [99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99],
                         [99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99],
                         [99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99]])

QF=99.0
if QF < 50 and QF > 1:
    scale = np.floor(5000/QF)
elif QF < 100:
    scale = 200-2*QF
else:
    print("Quality Factor must be in the range [1..99]")
    
scale=scale/100.0
Q=[QY*scale,QC*scale,QC*scale]

TransAll=[]
TransAllQuant=[]
for idx,channel in enumerate(Three_Channels):
    channelrows=channel.shape[0]
    channelcols=channel.shape[1]
    Trans = np.zeros((channelrows,channelcols), np.float32)
    TransQuant = np.zeros((channelrows,channelcols), np.float32)
    blocksV=channelrows/B
    blocksH=channelcols/B
    vis0 = np.zeros((channelrows,channelcols), np.float32)
    vis0[:channelrows, :channelcols] = channel
    vis0=vis0-128
    for row in range(blocksV):
        for col in range(blocksH):
            currentblock = cv2.dct(vis0[row*B:(row+1)*B,col*B:(col+1)*B])
            Trans[row*B:(row+1)*B,col*B:(col+1)*B]=currentblock
            TransQuant[row*B:(row+1)*B,col*B:(col+1)*B]=np.round(currentblock/Q[idx])
    TransAll.append(Trans)
    TransAllQuant.append(TransQuant)
```

The traceback is as follows:

runfile('C:/Users/Leith/Desktop/Malicious and Good Websites/FinalDataset/URL/untitled5.py', wdir='C:/Users/Leith/Desktop/Malicious and Good Websites/FinalDataset/URL')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Leith\Desktop\Malicious and Good Websites\FinalDataset\URL\untitled5.py", line 65, in 
for row in range(blocksV):

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Would you aid me please in exploring a way of fixing it up - I will be thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error should be here:

```
blocksV=channelrows/B
```

When dividing, python convert integers to floats. Even if you are dividing integers with integers and the result is supposed to be an integer (for example, 4/2 = 2.0 and not 2). Then `range(blocksV)` raises an error, because `range` accepts integer types as argoument, not float types.

Be sure that `blocksV` is an integer: you can use:

```
blocksV=channelrows//B
```

(note the `//` operator) which returns only the integer part of the division (any decimal is truncated), as a integer type.

You will have the same problem with `blocksH=channelcols/B`

EDIT

In addition to the previous statement, your real problem is the naming of the variable. You are redefining B.

```
B=8 # blocksize 
...
L,A,B=cv2.split(Trans_Color)
```

So when you are dividing and multiplying by B in the latest lines of the code with the `for` loops, I think you mean the blocksize, but actually `B` is the numpy array created by `cv2.split`. You need to use different names.

To avoid this in the future, you should use more explicit names (no single letter names, it will be more difficult to make this kind of error).

Comment: I also used the int function as blocksH=int(channelcols/B), but none of them can overcome the error yet!